# Typed events in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Currently I am manually casting an event:

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:modelValue', value: string | number): void
}>()

// [..]    

<input
  type="text"
  :value="modelValue"
  @input="emit('update:modelValue', ($event.target as // manually
HTMLInputElement).value)"                             // casted
/>
```

Is there any better way than this? Any way around having to cast it?

Hint: I am not using `v-model` here because the shown code is part of a component (on which `v-model` will be used then)

Comment: Will calling `emit('update:modelValue', $event)` not work? It's how they do it in the docs. Seems to send `event.target.value` by default

Comment: @Jason No, that does not work ): My text field then ends up with "[object InputEvent]" as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function instead of in-lining it to make for a nicer template, but it doesn't change that you have to cast it, as shown in the [official docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-event-handlers)

Also wanted to point out that the question is a little misleading, since

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:modelValue', value: string | number): void
}>()
```

has no bearing on the `@input` in the template. Including it in the question made me think at first that you expected that `defineEmits` could influence it.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the docs, I didn't see them at first. Nice to have an official source :-)